# SQL get the value above(larger) and below(smaller) of an inbetween value in a select statement

Tags: sql, select

I have a table containing two columns "allowable" and "thickness".

The thickness values are let say 1.2  2  3  4,3
I'm trying to write a udf which can take any thickness (eg2.3) and then it interpolates the allowable values. My question is if there is a smart (or maybe even out of the box) function which returns the upper and lower thickness value I need (2 and 3).
Regards, Lumpi
I'm using ms sql server 2008..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 'max', max(thickness) value from thicknesses where thickness < requirement 
union
select 'min', min(thickness) value from thicknesses where thickness > requirement
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice and clean way to do it !

Comment: Edited to add commas so you should get a "max" line and a "min" line.